# android listview searching getting null pointer error

Tags: android, listview

Hello all i want to add search funcationality to listview for that i have doen following

```
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (valueFilter == null) {
            valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
        }
        return valueFilter;
    }

    private class ValueFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {

                for (int i = 0; i < mStringFilterList.size()-1; i++) {
                    if ((mStringFilterList.get(i).getServiceName().toString())
                            .contains(constraint.toString())) {
                        // Contacts contacts = new Contacts();


                        contacts.setServiceName(mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                .getServiceName());
                        contacts.setAmount(mStringFilterList.get(i).getAmount()
                                + "");
                        System.out
                                .println("mStringFilterList.get(i).getAmount()"
                                        + mStringFilterList.get(i).getAmount());
                        contacts.setTrnDate(mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                .getTrnDate());
                        System.out
                                .println("mStringFilterList.get(i).getTrnDate()"
                                        + mStringFilterList.get(i).getTrnDate());
                        filterList.add(contacts);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            } else {
                results.count = mStringFilterList.size();
                results.values = mStringFilterList;
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
             list=(ArrayList<Contacts>) results.values;

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

}
```

But getting error on `mStringFilterList.get(i).getServiceName().toString())`

Comment: It'll help if you post the code for ***MyTransactionAdpter***

Comment: Still can't see where the cause might be, since according to the logs the NPE is in *MyTransactionAdpter.getCount(MyTransactionAdpter.java:39)*
@Hiren Patel's answer might be right though, you might just need to modify the ***getCount()*** in your adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update `getCount()` method:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}
```

**Reason:** You need to **return** **numbers** of **elements** stored in **ArrayList**.

Done